# R function to map SI prefixes to their values

Tags: r, dplyr, mapping

I have some data that's very poorly formatted; the key column defaulted to a character since it has symbols (e.g., ? and -), alphabetic, and numeric values. There are ~20 unique values. I would like to map everything in that column to a new column that is a collection of SI base 10 powers. I've tried doing this using the dplyr recode() function, but have not been successful. This is an example of the data that I have:

```
df <- data.frame(Type = letters[1:5], Value = c(5.2, 7, 42.5, 
1, 0.3), Exp = c("m", "k", "b", "6", "?"))

structure(list(Type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
Value = c(5.2, 7, 42.5, 1, 0.3), Exp = c("m", "k", "b", 
"6", "?")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The `exp` variable is the mess -- I think I need to be able to map `m` to `10^6` (for "million"), `k` to `10^3` (for "kilo"), etc. The `mapvalues()` function in `plyr` would work, but there are too many collisions between `dplyr` and `plyr` for me to load both.

Comment: Please be kind enough to show few lines of data with `dput` for testing. tahnks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide us a sample using `dput` so we can understand what you mean: I don't get how you can change a variable having symbols to SI values

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a table that contains the mapping and join it to the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Type = letters[1:5], 
    Value = c(5.2, 7, 42.5, 1, 0.3),
    Exp = c("m", "k", "b", "6", "?"))


units <- structure(list(SI = c("m", "k", "b", "6", "?"), 
    factor = c("1,00E+06", "1,00E+03", "1,00E+09", NA, NA)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>% left_join(units, by=c(Exp="SI"))

  Type Value Exp   factor
1    a   5.2   m 1,00E+06
2    b   7.0   k 1,00E+03
3    c  42.5   b 1,00E+09
4    d   1.0   6     <NA>
5    e   0.3   ?     <NA>
```

Comment: If it were a small number of points, then joining it to the original data frame would be OK, but they aren't in any kind of order and there are a large number of them.

Comment: If you are looking for an automatic way to find the correct prefix to the SI units, then you should rephrase your question. Can you post a `dput(unique(df$Exp))`?